# Plaid + Stripe transfer from my account to the authenticated bank account from Plaid

Tags: stripe-payments, plaid

Is there a way to like do a transfer from Stripe to a authenticated Plaid account?

In the Stripe docs there's a `transfer` object but it has a `destination` property which would be another Stripe account (correct me if I'm wrong).

I wonder if I could use the `bank_account_token` that would be generated in Plaid (when doing an ACH transfer) to be the `destination` to make my bank account linked in Stripe transfer to the other bank account that is authenticated by Plaid.

So it's like doing an ACH transfer but the other way around (from my account to the customers account)

Sorry for my bad english and thank you for anyone that can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you can't do the ACH Transfer the other way around (from Stripe to Plaid)

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has pretty comprehensive docs on how to integrate with Plaid: https://stripe.com/docs/ach#using-plaid

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it seems like you can't do the ACH Transfer the other way around